# Why TreePanel node & IE bug?

Tags: internet-explorer, extjs

I developed an application with TreePanel .
I have a strange behaviour with IE ( tested on IE 7 , 8 ) .

When i click on a node , the screen moves on a center of screen . 
Like it have a an anchor on my page ... !

My TreePanel is define likt this :

```
            var monPretree = Ext.create('Ext.tree.Panel',{
            id : 'treepanel',
            title : 'Tree Tasks',
            width : 500,
            animate : false,
            activeItem : 1,
            useArrows : true,
            autoScroll : true,
            singleExpand : false,
            store : monPrestore,
            enableDD : true,
            rootVisible : false,

            viewConfig : {
                plugins : {
                    ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'


                }

            },
```

I don't know where i can find a solution ... maybe somebody ever meet same problem ?

So, to resolved my problem , i would like if is possible to disable collapse node ? 
To have treePanel always Expand and forbidden a collapsible mode ?!

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to disallow a node from expanding. the most straightforward way is making it a leaf thus disallowing it to have children and making expanding impossble.
Mostly this is done serverside when retuning the JSON for the tree you just add an attribute `leaf:true` to each of the nodes that should not be expanded/opened.

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "name":"Node ONE",
      "leaf":true
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "name":"Node TWO",
      "leaf":true
   },
   {
      "id":"3",
      "name":"Node THREE",
      "leaf":true
   }
]
```

An alternate way of achieving this is by setting the expanded state to true and adding no children to the node, also serverside.

```
[
   {
      "id":"1",
      "name":"Node ONE",
      "expanded":true,
      "children":[]
   },
   {
      "id":"2",
      "name":"Node TWO",
      "expanded":true,
      "children":[]
   },
   {
      "id":"3",
      "name":"Node THREE",
      "expanded":true,
      "children":[]
   }
]
```

Comment: Thans to your answer, but if i "transform" each node on leaf , i loose my tree function ! I need to represent directory and file on my tree , i can't makes each node on leaf !

If i add , `Expanded : true` i not forbidden collapsible mode ?! And i not sur that solved the IE bug .. :(

Comment: So you want to still expand but not collapse? Concerning the IE bug do you get any javascript errors, check the developer console (F12).

Comment: Yes, i means if when i click on a node , the screens move maybe if i expand all node maybe than solved the problem !?
I haven't got errors on developer console .. ! 
Can't you test my code , if you see the "bug" ?

[link](http://www.play-host.net/files/1310820880.zip)
You must change , extjs' librairies link on index.html page !